# Are %20 and + the same in a http url?

Tags: http, urlencode

I know that %20 and + both decode to the same binary value (a space), and for most webservers, especially those that map to physical files they will point to the same resource.

But my question is, must a url like http://www.example.org/hello%20world point to the same resource as http://www.example.org/hello+world, are they canonically the same?

In HTTP/1.0 + didn't map to a space, so I'm specifically asking about HTTP/1.1.

Comment: Never considered this before, will be interesting to see the correct answer on this, nice question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*Only within the query string*: the plus sign is a reserved character, so must be encoded to pass an actual '+' in either the path or the query string.  It's use as a substitute for spaces is a W3C [Recommendation](http://www.w3.org/Addressing/URL/4_URI_Recommentations.html) which only applies to the query string:

> Within the query string, the plus sign
>   is reserved as shorthand notation for
>   a space. Therefore, real plus signs
>   must be encoded. This method was used
>   to make query URIs easier to pass in
>   systems which did not allow spaces.

URI Comparison ([RFC 2616](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec3.html#sec3.2.3)):

> When comparing two URIs to decide if
>   they match or not, a client SHOULD use
>   a case-sensitive octet-by-octet
>   comparison of the entire URIs, with
>   these exceptions:
>
> ```
>   - A port that is empty or not given is equivalent to the default
>     port for that URI-reference;
>
>     - Comparisons of host names MUST be case-insensitive;
>
>     - Comparisons of scheme names MUST be case-insensitive;
>
>     - An empty abs_path is equivalent to an abs_path of "/".
> ```
>
> Characters other than those in the
>   "reserved" and "unsafe" sets (see RFC
>   2396 [42]) are equivalent to their
>   ""%" HEX HEX" encoding.

Reserved characters ([RFC 2396](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2396.txt))

> ";" | "/" | "?" | ":" | "@" | "&" | "=" | "+" | "$" | ","

So, on the third go-around: there is nothing official that declares them to be the same thing.  Using '+' literally to direct `http://example.org/hello+world` to a directory called `hello+world` is incorrect, but there's nothing that says it should instead be considered equivalent to a space.

Comment: In the quoted section it says "**Within the query string,** the plus sign is reserved as shorthand notation for a space." Within a query string is not the same thing as within the url in general.  In the general case the answer is no, however it may be

Comment: In the OP's example of `http://www.example.org/hello%20world` and `http://www.example.org/hello+world` The section you quoted doesn't apply because it's not part of a query string.

Comment: @Davy8 - I think you've kicked me over to the correct answer now :)